# Trying to create bundle with ArrayList<string> and pass it to another activity VIA Intent

Tags: java, android

I hope someone can help me with the question. I have looked all over and tried many suggestions as to how to get bundles from one activity to another. Most suggestions I have tried and they still do not work, I thought the following code would work but it doesn't. I believe I am getting null when I try to get the bundle in the new activity. Here is the code:

In my SyncActivity Class I have this:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        // If there are paired devices
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // Loop through paired devices
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                deviceList.add(device.getName());
                deviceList.add(device.getAddress());
                deviceList.add(device.getUuids().toString());
            }
        }

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(SyncActivity.this, BlueToothConnThread.class);
        Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
        myBundle.putStringArrayList("DeviceList", deviceList);
        myIntent.putExtras(myBundle);
        startActivity(myIntent);
```

In my BlueToothConnThread Class I do this:

```
 public BlueToothConnThread() {

    Bundle dataBundle = getIntent().getExtras();    
    deviceList = dataBundle.getStringArrayList("DeviceList");
```

}

The error is thrown after I try to initialize dataBundle with the getIntent().getExtras(); Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Russell

Comment: your POJO/POGO or model class must implement Parcelable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot receive Bundle in some arbitrary method. You can get the bundle in OnCreate method of the Activity. Then only it works.

```
 public BlueToothConnThread extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle onSavedInstanceState) {
     //Some code

    Bundle dataBundle = getIntent().getExtras();    
    deviceList = dataBundle.getStringArrayList("DeviceList");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, This helped a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you pass it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ABC.this, DEF.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("ArrayList", yourArrayList);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

And here is how you get it.

```
Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
ArrayList<Bluetooth> bluetoothArrayList= (ArrayList<Bluetooth>) bundle.getSerializable("ArrayList");
```

I hope it helps :)